# Is there a FOSS alternative to ConvertXtoDVD?

Tags: dvd-backup

Any programs for Ubuntu that convert all videos to DVD format and then burn the results to DVD? I've usually gone with a combination of K3B and DVDeNG. I was just wondering if there was an all-in-one solution. Thank you.